# Allow, Allow Of, Allow For

Tags: meaning, prepositions, idioms

I am confused about the usages of "allow", "allow for" and "allow of".  Suppose police

is examining the evidence related to a bank robbery:

> 1. The evidence ***allows*** the possibility of an inside job.
> 2. The evidence ***allows for*** the possibility of an inside job.
> 3. The evidence ***allows of*** the possibility of an inside job.

I checked a number of dictionaries and google.  It seems that the usages in my three sentences are understandable English.  But what do native speakers on this forum think?

Answer (score 9):

***Allow*** and ***allow of*** have essentially the same meaning, “permit”. They differ in the sorts of complements they license.

- *Allow* licenses nominal phrases, gerund clauses (with optional possessive subjects), and infinitive clauses with objective subjects:

  > The evidence allows the possibility of an inside job.
  >   The evidence allows (our) considering the possibility of an inside job.
  >   The evidence allows us to consider the possibility of an inside job.
- *Allow of* licenses nominal phrases and gerund clauses, but not infinitive clauses:

  > The evidence allows of the possibility of an inside job.
  >   The evidence allows of (our) considering the possibility of an inside job.

*Allow of* has never been common, and it has practically disappeared today:
[image] <sup>—[*Google NGrams*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=allows+of%2Fallows&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28allows%20of%20/%20allows%29%3B%2Cc0)</sup>

***Allow for*** has a different meaning: it means to ‘take into account’ or ‘make provision for’. For instance, we might say:

> A contingency fund in the budget allows for unexpected costs.
>   ‘Fuzzy logic’ in the software allows for incomplete data.

We would not say that *the evidence allows for* a possibility, because evidence is not a viable subject for that action; it is rather your interpretation which must allow for possibilities:

> **A:** We concluded that the safe was robbed by professionals, very likely the Simister Gang.
>   **B:** Did you allow for the possibility that it was inside job?
>   **A:** Yes, we took that into account; everyone with access to the safe had an unbreakable alibi.

Note, however, that these terms are so similar that they ***allow of*** easy confusion, so in your reading you must ***allow for*** the possibility that the writers have misused whichever terms they use.